# Foreground Service doesnt work in Android 9 (API 28)

Tags: java, android

I want to have a foreground service and I wrote the codes.
But the problem is that the app works well on API 26 and below but not in API 28.
The problem in API 28 is that it works as a background service and if you close the app, service closes too.
Here is my code:
MyService:

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Process;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {

    private Context context = null;
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "ChargeScreenService";

    private Looper serviceLooper;
    private ServiceHandler serviceHandler;
    private BatteryBroadCast batteryBroadCast;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private Notification notification;

    // Handler that receives messages from the thread
    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
            // For our sample, we just sleep for 5 seconds.
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    batteryBroadCast = new BatteryBroadCast(MyService.this);
                    batteryBroadCast.chargingChanges();
                }
            });
            thread.start();
            // Stop the service using the startId, so that we don't stop
            // the service in the middle of handling another job
            //stopSelf(msg.arg1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // Start up the thread running the service. Note that we create a
        // separate thread because the service normally runs in the process's
        // main thread, which we don't want to block. We also make it
        // background priority so CPU-intensive work doesn't disrupt our UI.
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);

        thread.start();

        // Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
        serviceLooper = thread.getLooper();
        serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler(serviceLooper);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        createNotificationChannel();

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            notification = new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle("Hi")
                    .setContentText("Hello")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setTicker("HI")
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .build();

            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        } else {
            notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Hi")
                    .setContentText("Hello")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setTicker("HI")
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .build();
        }

        startForeground(1, notification);

        Message msg = serviceHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.arg1 = startId;
        serviceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // We don't provide binding, so return null
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "ChargeScreenService";
            String description = "Service";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
            // or other notification behaviors after this
            notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
...
startService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    startForegroundService(intent);
                } else {
                    startService(intent);
                }

            }
        });
...
```

Finally, I added the permission in AndroidManifest file.
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />`
And defined my service too.

```
<service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true" />
```

Testing devices:
Samsung galaxy J7 pro (Model number: SM-J730F) (real device)
Virtual device: Genymotion Android 6

Comment: Which phone you are using for testing

Comment: @amin Samsung galaxy J7 pro (Model number: SM-J730F)

Comment: do you see any crash logs?

Comment: @amin No just doesnt work well.

Answer (score 0):

If your app targets API level 26 or higher, the system imposes restrictions on running background services when the app itself isn't in the foreground. In most cases like this, your app should use a scheduled job instead.